Some congruences of altenating binomial sums with index as arithmetic progressions
In theorem 1.1 in Lundell "A divisibility property for stirling numbers" says following:
Theorem 1.1. Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $s, a, b$ be integers such that $0 \leq a<p-1$ and $0 \leq b<p$. Then for $s \geq 1$
(i) $$\sum_{k \geq 0}(-1)^k\binom{(s+1)(p-1)-a}{k p+b} \equiv 0 \quad\left(\bmod p^s\right) $$
(ii) $$(-1)^b \sum_{k \geq 0}(-1)^k\binom{s(p-1)}{k p+b} \equiv(-p)^{s-1} \quad\left(\bmod p^s\right)$$
(iii) $$\quad(-1)^b \sum_{k \geq 0}(-1)^k\binom{s(p-1)-1}{k p+b} \equiv \frac{2 b+s+1}{2}(-p)^{s-1}\left(\bmod p^s\right)$$
He says only "The proof is a straightforward but somewhat tedious induction on $s$" but I can't. How can we prove this interesting congruence?
